# Kaspersky compatibility on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, compatibility, window, kaspersky

I'm trying install Kaspersky 2013 version 13 on my Windows 8.1 pro and can't install.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by cant install? Post a screenshot perhaps....It runs fine on my Win 8.1

Comment: I can also confirm that it works on my system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KIS 2013 won't install to windows 8.1 but it does run if you install it to windows 8 and then upgrade to 8.1. I made the mistake of uninstalling KIS and now it won't install back onto my 8.1 system.
According to Kaspersky support there are no plans to make it compatible yet.

Answer (score 1):

you can see directions on how to upgrade here: http://support.kaspersky.com/windows8.1#section0.block0. Please let us know if this doesn't work for you.

-Kaspersky Lab